# Beginner, Confused as to how to solder a "Y Split" Molex Connector to a USB

Tags: soldering, wire, adapter

I am currently working on a project in which two small computer fans are powered from a USB port. I want to be able to get two laptop fans powered off of one USB slot.

I was looking into some solutions, and I found a power cord that matches exactly what I want to do. The thing I am confused is that when the power cable is split, the cables [image] double at the point it splits, which is also the point in which I want to solder to the USB wire. 
[image: USB Cable].

The problem I face is that the USB only has 4 single free cables , not two cables on top of each other **in each pin slot** like where the Y split Molex cable above, so I can confused as to how I would attach it to the USB if there is one more cable on all slots? **Are the cables attached at the end by one of those Molex pins, and then I just solder the pins to the exposed USB wire?**
[image]

Furthermore, there are two black wires **in seperate pins** on the Split Molex cable, which one would I solder to the USB, as I know the only red cable would be soldered to the only red cable on the usb.

In comments: How would I solder the Molex connector to a USB if the molex connector has 2 wires seperated into 4 sections (as the USB cable only has one wire separated into 4 sections). If you **look at my last picture**, would I just solder those metal pins directly to the exposed wire on the usb, or would I chop those pins off, solder the two wires on the molex together, then solder the now combined wires to the usb wire?

Comment: Computer fans use 12V. USB provides 5V. Now you know why you haven't found any premade adapters.

Comment: I am actually using laptop fans, which are 5v sorry.

Answer (score 2):

On such a Molex connector, *yellow* is for **+12VDC** and *red* for **+5VDC**. Both *black* wires are ground (**GND**) or **0V**, the return path. Either of the black wires will do... although, by convention, you might want to use the black wire that is close to the coloured cable for the power signal return path.

The yellow wire is useless for you since USB only has +5V on its (typically) red wire. you can then keep only the red wire and one of the black ones. Be sure to pair the wires that you keep with the fan's on the other connector.

You can safely chop the *data* wires (+ and -) off the USB cable. Better insulate them to prevent accidental shorting or contact with the power wires.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response; however, how would I solder the Molex connector to a USB if the molex connector has 2 wires seperated into 4 sections (as the USB cable only has one wire separated into 4 sections). If you **look at my last picture**, would I just solder those metal pins directly to the exposed wire on the usb, or would I chop those pins off, solder the two wires on the molex together, then solder the now combined wires to the usb wire?

Comment: In fact you don't need a Y cable as what you'll do is solder all the **black** wires together (USB and Molex)and all the **red** wires together (USB and Molex), leaving the other pin of each wire in its connector. Also protect the soldered areas with some [heat shrink tubing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat-shrink_tubing).

Comment: Thanks for your response: I will admit, I am a super beginner and I am a little lost. So how would I solder all the black wires together and all the red wires together? I thought we only solder the tips? **Anyways**, I would like to be able to de-attach the fans after I am done which is why I want to use the molex connectors, so I still don't know what to do with those double wires and how to connect them to the USB.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not available 24/7 (you know, nights...) «*So how would I solder [...]*» That brings us to the question before the next step: do you have a soldering iron and do you know how to solder?